# How do you use textures with transparency in three.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I would like to assemble a group of meshes like this:

[image: mesh grid]

The black outlined rectangles represent how I would like to assemble them. I have 8 pieces, 4 edges, and 4 corners, as textures (with transparency). Then, I have a 9th texture that I would like to have underneath the others, and that one is represented by the purple area. The geometries seem to be good, and the texture images are 16x16 pngs. First, I tried the basic approach with just MeshBasicMaterial, and I get my rectangles, but not my textures. Following some advice seen elsewhere on SO I tried something like this:

```
material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
            transparent: true,
            map: texture
        });
        material.needsUpdate = true;

        var materials = [];
        materials.push(material);

        materials.push(new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
            color: 0x000000,
            wireframe: true,
            transparent: true
        }));

        mesh = THREE.SceneUtils.createMultiMaterialObject(geom, materials);
```

But this did not work either. I've also tried using the ShaderMaterial but I guess I do not get GLSL well enough yet to make it work. How in the world do I get transparent png textures to map onto ShapeGeometries?

Comment: did u vary the opacity value opacity: 0 to 1 `material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ opacity: 0.6,
            transparent: true,
            map: texture
        });`